# Java servlet not called

Tags: java, servlets, http-status-code-404

I'm new in Java servlets so  I'll be appreciate for understanding. I am struggling with servlet. After sending registration form from html, servlet is not called. I literally tried many things to set it up, but every time I've got error:

Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Jan 13 11:23:30 GMT 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

It seems like html for is no redirecting to my servlet. I've even put simple sout do init() and anything happend.

Here's my java class:
I've even tried different annotations, like instead urlPatterns just name ="/registration" or just same "/registration"

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/registration")
public class Register extends HttpServlet {


public void init() throws ServletException {
    System.out.println("init");
}


@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("post");
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String name = request.getParameter("userName");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");

    System.out.println(name + password + email);

}
```

Here is my html file:
in action="" I've tried put "registration" and result is same as with "/registration"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Enter Your Name</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="/registration" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="userName">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1"
>
    <!-- Config here. -->
</web-app>
```

Insted of annotations I've tried to configure servlet by web.xml but it still didn't work.

EDIT:

Firstly I'm oppening http://localhost:8080/addUser.html, then passing datas. Secondly I'm redirected to http://localhost:8080/registration but the error is same.

Comment: Are you sure this is a Post ? Have you tried implementing `doGet()` and calling `doPost()` in it ?

Comment: I didn't. I'm not sure that here is problem, first of all the method init() should be called but it isn't. It does mean that html file isn't connected with my java class.

Comment: Instead of trying to work with a specific url, can you first try with urlPattern as `*` or `*.*` ? This will help you to understand if problem lies with url pattern or something else.

Comment: I've tried it and result is same.